# Autonumber reset per day with Java Using Database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, string, auto-increment

I build some software for my mini shop, I really confused with number queue customer who shop in my place. Please someone could help me.
I have a method which content with generate new number of queue from my customer. But when I open my Apps in the next day, I hope the queue is reset into 1 again.

My sytax Java like =

```
public void acak() {
    try {
        String generate = "SELECT COALESCE (MAX(no_antrian),0) AS kode from transaksi  where tg_transaksi='" + tanggal + "'";
        Statement stat = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet res = stat.executeQuery(generate);
        if (res.next()) {
            try {
                String kd_barang = res.getString("kode").substring(1);
                String AN = "" + (Integer.parseInt(kd_barang) + 1);
                String Nol = "";
                if (AN.length() == 1) {
                    Nol = "000";
                } else if (AN.length() == 2) {
                    Nol = "00";
                } else if (AN.length() == 3) {
                    Nol = "0";
                } else if (AN.length() == 4) {
                    Nol = "";
                } 
                lblnoantrian.setText(Nol + AN);
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            lblnoantrian.setText("0001");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I run this program in the next day, I see the eror like :

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:504)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
```

this eror's refers to:

```
String AN = "" + (Integer.parseInt(kd_barang) + 1);
```

maybe anyone can helping me..

Comment: Adding the line `System.out.println(res.getString("kode").substring(1));` above the line throwing the exception should help you track down the problem

Comment: I cant see the problem with your guess,I guess I miss in String input, but I cannot fix it.

Comment: i think res.getString("kode").substring(1) is returning an empty string

Comment: Ya, but I've put value 0 in my syntax SQL SELECT COALESCE (MAX(no_antrian),0) when result is NULL.. @Programmer

Answer (score 0):

this is not the proper use of COALESCE

as its description says

**Returns the first non-NULL value in the list, or NULL if there are no non-NULL values.**

```
 mysql> SELECT COALESCE(NULL,1);
      -> 1
 mysql> SELECT COALESCE(NULL,NULL,NULL);
      -> NULL
```

in case there is a empty string so its output would be empty string check

```
SELECT COALESCE (MAX(NULL),0) 
    ->0

SELECT COALESCE (MAX(''),0) 
    ->

SELECT COALESCE ('',0) 
   ->
```

as you can see the last two queries returns empty string

replace your query with this query i hope this will work

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN COALESCE (MAX(no_antrian), 0) = '' 
     THEN 0 
    ELSE COALESCE(MAX(no_antrian), 0) 
  END AS kodec  
FROM
  transaksi 
WHERE tg_transaksi = '" + tanggal + "' "
```

Comment: doesn`t matter because MAX(no_antrian) is returning an empty string

Comment: replace your query with my query i have added just now in my answer

Comment: what do you mean by (but I cant reset from 1 when next day).?

Comment: I mean, if today my queue is until 0090, then tommorow when I open my app is still 0090 , I hope this queue is reset automatically to 0001 when day change.

Comment: When I used your query, the queue is stay in zero result

Comment: it is because your MAX(no_antrian) returns empty string

Comment: do you want your query to reset no_antrian every next day to from 0001?

Comment: how do you know that its a next day ? is there any date columns in your table etc can you rewrite your question with table and expected output

Comment: the answer was given as per your question where you were facing a NumberFormatException and you wanted to have 0 if it returns Null or empty string